# Pycharm - (1) after filename in "Run" menu

Tags: pycharm, ubuntu-18.04

I've been reorganizing the internal structure of a project, moving files around, separating folders and such.

Now, in the Run menu some files appear with a (1) added after their name, as you can see in the attached picture:

[image]

It generally happens if I have multiple instances of a script running, but that's not the case here.
I committed everything after the modifications, but it doesn't seem to be related to that.

No big deal clearly, but I was wondering how to fix that.

Comment: It just means there are multiple run configurations with the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call the "run menu" is what Pycharm calls "run configurations". Pycharm automatically creates these when you try to run a file. It looks like at one point, you already had a run configuration named analyze_clips, so PyCharm added a new one with the "(1)" at the end. You can clean this all up by clicking on the drop down and selecting "Edit Run Configurations...". You can either rename configurations you want to keep or delete ones you don't.

For more details about working with run configurations, see [the Pycharm documenation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before too, and one of my solutions was to delete the ".idea" folder in the project folder, then restart PyCharm and it will recreate the folder. Usually I think it's because you changed the parent folder or path name after creating the ".idea" folder.